# Server 2012 R2 blue screen when mouse is plugged in

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, drivers

I have a server (Lenovo TD340) running 2012 R2 standard.  I've been using the server without a mouse for a while as I didn't have one handy.  Recently got a mouse (Logitech USB) and hooked it up. Moments later it started working as expected.  But the next time I tried to reboot the server I get a:

pnp_detected_fatal_error

BSOD on startup and the server won't boot.

Removed mouse -- server boots normally.  First time I've seen a mouse bring down a server.

Noticed in the Device Manager there are 3 "USB HID Compliant Mouse" listed.  I try removing them all and restarting with mouse plugged in. Server boots ok, but reinstalls the 3 drivers again. And sure enough on next boot I get the BSOD error.

So I disable 2 of the entries leaving only one.  Server now boots normally on subsequent reboots with mouse plugged in so my problem is "solved". But the solution seems inelegant and I fear I may have a deeper problem.

Any ideas on how I can more permanently resolve this problem so that Windows does not try to install multiple drivers.

(Also, I've tried multiple different mice)

Comment: Do you use a USB hub ? Remove it if so. Did you try a standard mouse, like the one that ship with the server

Comment: No USB hub.  No mouse/keyboard shipped with the server.  But this is a pretty standard Logitech wired mouse: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA1N82KJ1783

Comment: If no hub, I think of a usb controller failure. Can you update the firmware of the motherboard and after try other usb device.